# react-router convert const into a class with subroutes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just copy and paste this example ( https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config ) from the official documentation of react-router and this works perfectly but I dont like using a const for these components so I like using a class as component instead it so , I wonder how can I convert this const into a class react component?

```
const Tacos = ({ routes }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Tacos</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/tacos/bus">Bus</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/tacos/cart">Cart</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    {routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />)}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called functional stateless components. They are actually preferred to classes if you don't have any state or methods that you need to attach to the class as they are more light weight and provide a slight performance enhancement in React. Here's how you would write it as a class:

```js
import RouteWithSubRoutes from './utils/RouteWithSubRoutes';

class Tacos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Tacos</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos/bus">Bus</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/tacos/cart">Cart</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
    {this.props.routes.map((route, i) => <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi bro very helpful,this works perfectly ,thank you so much,good luck in your life.